# Problems rotating a model in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, 3dsmax

I'm new to 3D models so apologises if these seems basic. I've been searching the web and through my books but I'm lost.

I've made a model in 3D Studio Max 9. It consists of a variety of cubes, clyinders etc.

In Xna I've imported the model okay and it shows correctly. However, when I apply rotation, each component in the model rotates around it's own centre rather. I want the model to rotate as a singal unit rather than each component rotating on the spot.

I've linked the components in 3D Max and they rotate as I want in Max.

```cs
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    model = Content.Load<Model>("Models/Alien1");
}


protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    camera.Update(1f, new Vector3(), graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio);
    rotation += 0.1f;
    base.Update(gameTime);
}


protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
    model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);
    Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.Identity;
    Matrix rotationYMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotation);
    Matrix translateMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(location);

    worldMatrix = rotationYMatrix * translateMatrix;

    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
        {
            effect.World = worldMatrix * transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
            effect.View = camera.viewMatrix;
            effect.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix;

            effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
        }
        mesh.Draw();
    }


    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

EDIT: Rotating the object via it's properties works fine so I'm guessing there's something up with the code rather than with the object itself.
Translating the object also causes the objects to get moved independently of each other rather than as a single model and each piece becomes spread around the scene.

Comment: You should try inverting the order when multiplying matrices, maybe where you're defying effect.World.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work...

Comment: You are sure that it doesn't work if you specify `effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * worldMatrix;`? Well, that can't really be. Or you'll have to redefine "it does not work".

Comment: Ah my mistake. I had misread the answer I altered the order of multiplication with the "worldMatrix = rotationYMatrix * translateMatrix;" instead.
Sorry...
Thanks for sorting it :)